# Keyboard not working on Thinkpad X1 Carbon 2nd Generation (model 20A8)

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, thinkpad

Dear Ubuntu Community,

I just installed ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop thinkpad x1 carbon 2nd generation (model 20A8). But i never got the keyboard to work. It didnt work during the installation and I had to use the virtual keyboard. The usb mouse works.

What can I do to troubleshoot? Is there any drivers/package that could fix this issue?

I've been googling for a while and didnt find anything helpful... Hence my post here on this forum!

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with xorg.
Quick fix available at https://techwiser.com/fix-keyboard-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04/